# When it is worth to use class function returning reference to itself?

Tags: c++, class

Let's assume we have a class in c++:

```
Class SomeClass{
     SomeClass& fun();
}
```

and the question is about function fun()

```
SomeClass &SomeClass::fun()
{
    //do some stuff
    return *this;
}
```

Where it comes with advantage to use function that returns reference to object itself? Or when it's disadvantage?

I know already:

- + chaining (Thanks, I couldn't find name for it)
- + operator overloading
- - It may cause problems in structures based on Inheritance (from chaining)

Comment: "*fun2 some other stuff not connected with object*" : this is impossible with your definition of *fun*. Because *fun* return* the instance (e.g. the value of *object*) that implies *fun2* is also a method of *SomeClass* and in *object.fun().fun2()* it applies on the same instance than *fun* (e.g. the value of *object*)

Comment: Wrong written. I meant it's not doing changes on object properties, but takes use of them e.g int Rectangle::CalculateArea(){return m_x * m_y;}

Comment: Strange. *fun* does not know and does not have to know if the returned reference will be used or not in a 'cascaded' form, nor if the cascaded method will modify or not the instance. In what the fact *fun2* modify or not the instance is relevant in that history ?  You make me lost

Comment: Not relevant. I'll try to edit post to make question more clear.

Comment: Your question was closed. Sorry to say but I am afraid the best thing you have to do is to delete your question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Method "chaining" is a fairly common pattern in some languages, especially Ruby, Python and to a degree JavaScript. It's a valid pattern to employ in C++ even if you don't see it as often.

As idclev points out, the C++ stream system uses this pervasively:

```
std::cout << example << value << std::endl;
```

Where in each case `operator<<` returns a reference to the `stream`, effectively, so you can keep chaining on more operations to it.

Using different semantics this is similar to:

```
std::cout.write(example).write(value).write(std::endl);
```

Internally `operator<<` is defined by the type being written, so it's more complicated than this.

Comment: not in this exact form, but it is super common with `std::cout`

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's a great example of C++-native chaining.

Comment: sorry but the operator is **not** defined on the stream class but on the class typing *exemple* and *value*, so the friend operator << so not return *this

Comment: @bruno Where it's defined isn't as relevant as the chaining principle itself.

Comment: @tadman in the OP example it was for the same class, this is why I warn you

Comment: @bruno A good caveat to add, but it doesn't invalidate the idea. If you know of anything in the Standard Library that does this more directly, worth noting.

Comment: i agree that a bit of sloppyness is appropriate, but I would change the wording to be a bit more vague, maybe not meantion `*stream` at all, because non-member function overloads of `<<` take the stream by reference and return that reference

Comment: suggestion: "Where in each case operator<< returns a reference to the stream"

Comment: hehe ninja'd ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Already done.

Comment: Since the OP edited his question to push-out the operators our answers speaking about operator are not anymore an answer ... ;-)